# Load Data from another file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, load-data-infile

I am doing some calculations in MATLAB on a data from a particular cell(biological) type and obtain some plots at the end of it. I do simlilar kind of calculations on data from another cell type, by running the same program, using the same variables, but on different files( the files have the data).
I want to plot the lines obtained from one cell type in the same figure as the lines from the second cell type to compare the behaviour.
Is there a way I can save the waveforms obtained earlier into a vector, then load the vector and, use it to plot waveforms from both cells on same figure?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for the `hold on` functionality:

```
>> A=1:0.1:5;
>> B=A.*A;
>> figure(1);
>> hold on;
>> plot(A,A,'bo');
>> plot(A,B,'rd');
>> hold off;
```

This gives:

[image]